# How to boot from fully encrypted root partition using systemd-boot - PopOS style?

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

While attempting a dual-boot setup on my laptop, I accidentally deleted the original bootloader that was automatically installed with the GUI. I followed this guide: [System76 Bootloader Guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/). However, every time I reboot, I receive the following error: `cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device and then UUID of the encrypted drive`.

Here's my `/etc/crypttab` file, originally generated by the Pop OS install:

```
cryptdata UUID={uuid} none luks
cryptswap UUID={uuid} /dev/urandom swap,plain,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512
```

I executed these commands to mount my encrypted partition:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 cryptdata
sudo lvscan
sudo vgchange -ay
sudo mount /dev/mapper/data-root /mnt
```

After entering my password, the encrypted partition mounted successfully.

Then, I executed these commands to mount the EFI partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
```

and continued with tutorial steps

```
for i in dev dev/pts proc sys run; do sudo mount -B /$i /mnt/$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
update-initramfs -c -k all
exit
sudo bootctl --path=/mnt/boot/efi install
```

All commands executed without issues, except for a minor Python error when running `update-initramfs`. The error asked if I was running in a `chroot` environment, which I was, so I ignored it.

After restarting, I saw the Linux boot entry, but attempting to boot resulted in the error described above. I've verified that all UUIDs are correct. What am I missing?

Comment: Your bootloader (probably GRUB) needs also to have the LVM module besides the LUKS module. Currently it seems your boot loader cannot handle LVM and thus cannot find the root partition. Often it gives no practical advantage to encrypt the root partition, also installing the root partition on LVM is often problematic. I suggest never to encrypt root partition and always use a conventional partition table for root. I use LVM and encryption mostly for `/home` and other sensitive data or data which is able to grow significant in size.

Comment: I probably should follow your advice, but it was default installation. I see where you comming from.